# python dictionary object vs value

Tags: python, dictionary

i am still not quite familiar with the programmation language and i am struggling to understand the difference between low_price which returns a value and high_price which returns (apparently) an object. Can someone explain me why they have different structure?
Both are dictionary. high_price is getting through a function. Hope it makes sense. Apologies if the indentation isnt correct, i am still struggling to get this right with the website aswell!

```
Output
{0: {...}} 
({0: {...}}, 99.9969999999999)

def agregate_freq(freq, high_price,low_price):    
    if mynumber >high_price[0]: #new one
        high_price[0] = mynumber
    #if mynumber <low_price[0]: #new one
    #    low_price[0] = mynumber
    print(high_price[0])
    return (high_price)

    if mynumber <low_price[0]: #new one
        low_price[0] = mynumber

    high_price[0] = agregate_freq(0,high_price,low_price)
    print (high_price[0],low_price[0])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return (high_price)` just returns the value of the expression `high_price` and *not* a tuple as expected. `(high_price[0],low_price[0])` is a tuple. If you want a single element tuple, put a comma after your `high_price`; something like `return (high_price,)`.

This is the reason why there is a difference between the output seen.

Answer (score 1):

When you do `high_price[0] = agregate_freq(0,high_price,low_price)`, you're setting the 0th element of `high_price` to be the return value of your `agregate_freq` function. That function returns `high_price` itself, so strangely I think you're setting the first element of `high_price` to be `high_price` itself. You're not doing that to `low_price`.
I'm just guessing, but your function seems to be doing the assignment itself, so you probably don't want it returning anything. Just call `agregate_freq(0,high_price,low_price)` on its own, and that might do what you're looking for.